# Using Case Is with Named Column

Tags: vba, excel

I cant get this (simple) VBA formula to work (in Excel 2010). I want the formula to evaluate cell B2. If B2 is blank, I want C2 to be blank. If B2 > 0, I want C2 to populate with the word "success". Then I want the program to evaluate B3, B4, B5, etc (through B20) using the same logic as above. In other words, for each Bx, I want one of two cases. Case 1) a blank value in Bx generates a blank in the corresponding Cx or Case 2) a value greater than 0 in Bx generates the word "success" in the corresponding Cx. When I run the macro, I don't get an error message, but nothing happens in column C. The debugger tells me the problem is in the Comment.Name = "Comment" line but I cant figure out what's wrong. thanks!

```
Sub AutoComplete()
    Dim Comment As Range
    Set Comment = Range("C2:C20")
    Comment.Name = "Comment"
    For i = 2 To 20
        Select Case Range("B" & i).Value
            Case Is > 0
                StartDate = "Success"
            Case Is = " "
                StartDate = " "
        End Select
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: During figuring out what is wrong, did you try to use **F8** key to trace execution of the macro? Then you can hover mouse cursor over variables (among other things) to see their values.

Comment: First you say that the macro runs without error, but then you say that the debugger breaks on line `Comment.Name = ...`.  It can't happen both ways. Either you get an error, or you do not. Please clarify.  Also, please indicate what type of data (with examples, if possible) is in the range of cells to be examined ("B2:B20")

Comment: I note that nothing in this code actually assigns a value out to the range in column C, so that is probably the explanation. **ALWAYS** declare all of your variables (`StartDate` is not declared, and it is the fact that you probably forgot to use this variable then to update the cell in column C).

Answer (score 2):

You're not writing anything to column C. You're putting a value in the variable StartDate but not doing anything with it. You're also not doing anything with the Comment range. The following will write to Column C

```
Range("C" & i).Value = "Success"
```

Comment: I'd say just before `Next i` use `Range("C" & i).Value = StartDate`